# How to generate random date between two dates using php?

Tags: php, date, datetime, timestamp

I am coding an application where i need to assign random date between two fixed timestamps

how i can achieve this using php i've searched first but only found the answer for Java not php

for example :

```
$string = randomdate(1262055681,1262055681);
```

Comment: Is it me, or the limits are the same? :)

Comment: as of 2016 @Sam s answer should be the accepted one since we all should move to `DateTime` instead of using `date`-functions.

Comment: -1: The two imputed time stamps are equal? You wont get any random!
+1 because its a good question.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

PHP has the [rand()](http://ca.php.net/rand) function:

```
$int= rand(1262055681,1262055681);
```

It also has [mt_rand()](http://ca.php.net/mt_rand), which is generally purported to have better randomness in the results:

```
$int= mt_rand(1262055681,1262055681);
```

To turn a timestamp into a string, you can use [date()](http://php.net/date), ie:

```
$string = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$int);
```

Comment: To add to that, once your random number comes out, treat it as a new timestamp and construct a date from it.

Comment: @Sudhir - definitely.  @NetCaster - You can use the `date()` function to create a date string out of a timestamp very easily.

Comment: See @Sam s answer for an up-to-date solution using `DateTime`

Answer (score 50):

If given dates are in date time format then use this easiest way of doing this is to convert both numbers to timestamps, then set these as the minimum and maximum bounds on a random number generator.

A quick PHP example would be:

```
// Find a randomDate between $start_date and $end_date
function randomDate($start_date, $end_date)
{
    // Convert to timetamps
    $min = strtotime($start_date);
    $max = strtotime($end_date);

    // Generate random number using above bounds
    $val = rand($min, $max);

    // Convert back to desired date format
    return date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $val);
}
```

This function makes use of [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) as suggested by zombat to convert a datetime description into a Unix timestamp, and date() to make a valid date out of the random timestamp which has been generated.

Answer (score 34):

Another solution using PHP [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

`$start` and `$end` are [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) objects and we convert into Timestamp. Then we use [`mt_rand`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php) method to get a random Timestamp between them. Finally we recreate a [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object.

```
function randomDateInRange(DateTime $start, DateTime $end) {
    $randomTimestamp = mt_rand($start->getTimestamp(), $end->getTimestamp());
    $randomDate = new DateTime();
    $randomDate->setTimestamp($randomTimestamp);
    return $randomDate;
}
```

Comment: We should all move to `DateTime` instead of `date()`-functions. That being said, this is the best solution.

Comment: great solution love the \DateTime usage

Answer (score 31):

You can just use a random number to determine a random date. Get a random number between 0 and number of days between the dates. Then just add that number to the first date.

For example, to get a date a random numbers days between now and 30 days out.

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime( '+'.mt_rand(0,30).' days'));
```

Answer (score 9):

Here's another example:

```
$datestart = strtotime('2009-12-10');//you can change it to your timestamp;
$dateend = strtotime('2009-12-31');//you can change it to your timestamp;

$daystep = 86400;

$datebetween = abs(($dateend - $datestart) / $daystep);

$randomday = rand(0, $datebetween);

echo "\$randomday: $randomday\n";

echo date("Y-m-d", $datestart + ($randomday * $daystep)) . "\n";
```

Answer (score 9):

The best way :

```
$timestamp = rand( strtotime("Jan 01 2015"), strtotime("Nov 01 2016") );
$random_Date = date("d.m.Y", $timestamp );
```

Comment: Very elegant solution. Thanks.

Comment: Good. mt_rand vs rand  https://stackoverflow.com/a/28760905/624533

Answer (score 7):

By using [carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) and php [rand](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php) between two dates

```
$startDate = Carbon::now();
$endDate   = Carbon::now()->subDays(7);

$randomDate = Carbon::createFromTimestamp(rand($endDate->timestamp, $startDate->timestamp))->format('Y-m-d');
```

OR

```
$randomDate = Carbon::now()->subDays(rand(0, 7))->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 6):

An other solution where we can use date_format :

```
 /**
 * Method to generate random date between two dates
 * @param $sStartDate
 * @param $sEndDate
 * @param string $sFormat
 * @return bool|string
 */

function randomDate($sStartDate, $sEndDate, $sFormat = 'Y-m-d H:i:s') {
    // Convert the supplied date to timestamp
    $fMin = strtotime($sStartDate);
    $fMax = strtotime($sEndDate);
    // Generate a random number from the start and end dates
    $fVal = mt_rand($fMin, $fMax);
    // Convert back to the specified date format
    return date($sFormat, $fVal);
}
```

Source : https://gist.github.com/samcrosoft/6550473

You could use for example :

```
$date_random = randomDate('2018-07-09 00:00:00','2018-08-27 00:00:00');
```

Answer (score 4):

The amount of `strtotime` in here is WAY too high.
For anyone whose interests span before 1971 and after 2038, here's a modern, flexible solution:

```
function random_date_in_range( $date1, $date2 ){
    if (!is_a($date1, 'DateTime')) {
        $date1 = new DateTime( (ctype_digit((string)$date1) ? '@' : '') . $date1);
        $date2 = new DateTime( (ctype_digit((string)$date2) ? '@' : '') . $date2);
    }
    $random_u = random_int($date1->format('U'), $date2->format('U'));
    $random_date = new DateTime();
    $random_date->setTimestamp($random_u);
    return $random_date->format('Y-m-d') .'<br>';
}
```

Call it any number of ways ...

```
// timestamps
echo random_date_in_range(157766400,1489686923);

// any date string
echo random_date_in_range('1492-01-01','2050-01-01');

// English textual parsing
echo random_date_in_range('last Sunday','now');

// DateTime object
$date1 = new DateTime('1000 years ago');
$date2 = new DateTime('now + 10 months');
echo random_date_in_range($date1, $date2);
```

As is, the function requires `date1` <= `date2`.

Answer (score 1):

i had a same situation before and none of the above answers fix my problem so i

Came with new function

```
function randomDate($startDate, $endDate, $count = 1 ,$dateFormat = 'Y-m-d H:i:s')
{
   //inspired by
    // https://gist.github.com/samcrosoft/6550473

    // Convert the supplied date to timestamp
    $minDateString = strtotime($startDate);
    $maxDateString = strtotime($endDate);

    if ($minDateString > $maxDateString) 
    {
        throw new Exception("From Date must be lesser than to date", 1);

    }

    for ($ctrlVarb = 1; $ctrlVarb <= $count; $ctrlVarb++) 
    { 
       $randomDate[] = mt_rand($minDateString, $maxDateString); 
    }
    if (sizeof($randomDate) == 1) 
    {
        $randomDate = date($dateFormat, $randomDate[0]);
        return $randomDate;
    }elseif (sizeof($randomDate) > 1) 
    {
        foreach ($randomDate as $randomDateKey => $randomDateValue) 
        {
           $randomDatearray[] =  date($dateFormat, $randomDateValue);
        }
        //return $randomDatearray;
        return array_values(array_unique($randomDatearray));
    }
}
```

Now the testing Part(Data may change while testing )

```
$fromDate = '2012-04-02';
$toDate = '2018-07-02';
```

print_r(randomDate($fromDate,$toDate,1));

result will be

```
2016-01-25 11:43:22
```

print_r(randomDate($fromDate,$toDate,1));

```
array:10 [▼
  0 => "2015-08-24 18:38:26"
  1 => "2018-01-13 21:12:59"
  2 => "2018-06-22 00:18:40"
  3 => "2016-09-14 02:38:04"
  4 => "2016-03-29 17:51:30"
  5 => "2018-03-30 07:28:48"
  6 => "2018-06-13 17:57:47"
  7 => "2017-09-24 16:00:40"
  8 => "2016-12-29 17:32:33"
  9 => "2013-09-05 02:56:14"
]
```

But after the few tests i was thinking about  what if the inputs be like

```
$fromDate ='2018-07-02 09:20:39';
$toDate = '2018-07-02 10:20:39';
```

So the duplicates may occur while generating the large number of dates such as `10,000`

so i have added `array_unique` and this will return only the non duplicates

Answer (score 1):

if you use laravel then it's for you.

```
\Carbon\Carbon::now()->subDays(rand(0, 90))->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 0):

**Simplest of all, this small function works for me**
I wrote it in a helper class `datetime` as a static method

```
/**
 * Return date between two dates
 *
 * @param String $startDate
 * @param String $endDate
 * @return String
 *
 * @author Kuldeep Dangi <kuldeepamy@gmail.com>
 */
public static function getRandomDateTime($startDate, $endDate)
{
    $randomTime = mt_rand(strtotime($startDate), strtotime($endDate));
    return date(self::DATETIME_FORMAT_MYSQL, $randomTime);

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Pretty good question; needed to generate some random sample data for an app.

You could use the [following function](https://gist.github.com/phpfiddle/b0816acab8d7ca36767b9ad08102426d) with optional arguments to generate random dates:

```
function randomDate($startDate, $endDate, $format = "Y-M-d H:i:s", $timezone = "gmt", $mode = "debug")
{
    return $result;
}
```

sample input:

```
echo 'UTC: ' . randomDate("1942-01-19", "2016-06-03", "Y-M-d H:i:s", "utc") . '<br>';
//1942-Jan-19 07:00:00

echo 'GMT: ' . randomDate("1942-01-19", "2016-06-03", "Y/M/d H:i A", "gmt") . '<br>'; 
//1942/Jan/19 00:00 AM

echo 'France: ' . randomDate("1942-01-19", "2016-06-03", "Y F", "Europe/Paris") . '<br>';
//1942 January

echo 'UTC - 4 offset time only: ' . randomDate("1942-01-19", "2016-06-03", "H:i:s", -4) . '<br>';
//20:00:00

echo 'GMT +2 offset: ' . randomDate("1942-01-19", "2016-06-03", "Y-M-d H:i:s", 2) . '<br>';
//1942-Jan-19 02:00:00

echo 'No Options: ' . randomDate("1942-01-19", "2016-06-03") . '<br>';
//1942-Jan-19 00:00:00
```

readers requirements could vary from app to another, in general hope this function is a handy tool where you need to generate some random dates/ sample data for your application.

**Please note** that the function initially in debug mode, so change it to `$mood=""` other than debug in production .

The function accepts:

1. start date
2. end date
3. format: any php accepted format for date or time
4. timezone: name or offset number
5. mode: debug, epoch, verbose epoch or verbose

the output in **not debug** mode is random number according to optional specifications.

tested with PHP 7.x

Answer (score -1):

```
// Find a randomDate between $startDate and $endDate
function randomDate($startDate, $endDate)
{
    // Convert to timetamps
    $min = strtotime($startDate);
    $max = strtotime($endDate);

    // Generate random number using above bounds
    $val = rand($min, $max);

    // Convert back to date
    return Carbon::createFromTimestamp($val);
}

dd($this->randomDate('2014-12-10', Carbon::now()->toString()));
```

Using carbon

Answer (score -3):

```
$yeni_tarih = date('Y-m-d', strtotime( '+'.mt_rand(-90,0).' days'))." ".date('H', strtotime( '+'.mt_rand(0,24).' hours')).":".rand(1,59).":".rand(1,59);
```

Full random date and time