# php/mysql ordered random dates

Tags: php, mysql, date

I found this great function on SO whilst looking for a way to generate random dates between two fixed timestamps:

```
 function randomDate($start_date, $end_date)
{
    // Convert to timestamps
    $min = strtotime($start_date);
    $max = strtotime($end_date);

    // Generate random number using above bounds
    $val = rand($min, $max);

    // Convert back to desired date format
    return date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $val);
}
```

[Source and credit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972712/generate-random-date-between-two-dates-using-php/10103901#10103901)

but I am looking for a way for the dates to be generated in order (start date to end date) as I have used it to generate dates to insert into a database.

The problem is my posts are `ORDER BY id DESC` and using the function "as is" being that they are random the dates end up out of sync.

**ie:**

```
post id 4 - date = 2010-07-11 14:14:10
post id 3 - date = 2012-02-22 18:23:21
post id 2 - date = 2011-03-17 13:52:47
post id 1 - date = 2011-08-14 15:33:50
```

and I need them to be in sync with the post id.

Now your thinking why not change the query to `ORDER BY date DESC` instead? ...well that would mess up 99% of code I have already written as there are other columns/rows dependent on it being `ORDER BY id DESC` and so ordering the dates when being inserted into the database is the only solution.

**update:**

this is what I tried using madfriend code but all dates are the same where have I gone wrong?

```
function randomDate($startdate, $enddate){
 $min = strtotime($startdate);
 $max = strtotime($enddate);
 $val = rand($min, $max);
 return date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $val);
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM foo";
$num   = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($query));

$randate = randomDate('2010-07-12 09:13:40', '2012-06-12 09:13:40');

$dates = array($randate);
for ($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++) {
    $dates[] = randomDate($startdate, $enddate);
}
sort($dates);
while($date = array_shift($dates)) {

$update = "UPDATE foo SET date='{$date}'";
 mysql_query($update);

}
```

plus getting 
`Notice: Undefined variable: startdate`

Comment: What you mean with sync with the post id? Could you provide more info?

Comment: @drupality he means that post with bigger id should have bigger timestamp

Comment: @Anna Riekic 'so ordering the dates when being inserted into the database is the only solution', May be this is holding you back.

Comment: @drupality latest post id should have the latest date.

Comment: @Rishi Kalia I could leave the date out but its a small feature I like to keep

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure whether you are talking about creation or modification of existing rows.

*Updates*: basic idea here is quite simple. First, count number of posts with `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM your_posts_table` query. After that:

```
// $num is number of posts
$dates = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++) {
    $dates[] = randomDate($startdate, $enddate);
}
sort($dates); // Sort dates in ascending order
while($date = array_shift($dates)) {
    // now $date won't be lower than it was in previous iterations.
    // use it to update your table
}
```

*Insertions*: If you are talking about insertions and want to make latest post date random but biggest, here's what you do:

- First, select last added post date.
- Second, call `randomDate` with `$startdate` set to the date of last added post.
- Last, insert new row with this date.

Comment: @AnnaRiekic the reason dates are the same is that your `update` doesn't have `where` statement, so each query affects *all* rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
function randomDate($startdate, $enddate){
 $min = strtotime($startdate);
 $max = strtotime($enddate);
 $val = rand($min, $max);
 return date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $val);
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM foo";
$num   = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($query));

$randate = randomDate('2010-07-12 09:13:40', '2012-06-12 09:13:40');

$dates = array($randate);
for ($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++) {
    $dates[] = randomDate($startdate, $enddate);
}
sort($dates);
while($date = array_shift($dates)) {
```

This query updates all rows in one go:

```
$update = "UPDATE foo SET date='{$date}' ";
 mysql_query($update);

}
```

Probably were wanting to use

```
$update = "update foo set date='{$date}' where id = (select id from foo where date is not null order by id limit 1)";
```

(for that to work you need to set each date in the db to null before you start updating: `update foo set date=null`)

Also you shouldn't be using myslq_query..