# Generate Randomy birth date

Tags: php

This is my code:

```
$curr_year = date('Y');
$dob_year  = rand($curr_year-18,$curr_year-47);
$dob_month = rand(01,12);
$dob_day   = rand(01,30);

echo $dob = $dob_month.'/'.$dob_day.'/'.$dob_year;
```

And I am getting result as `1/2/1988`, but my requirement is result should be `01/02/1988`

Comment: Try looking at [number_format](http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

Comment: I pity the randomly generated creature born on the 30th of February.

Comment: +1 for inventing a new word `randomy`.

Comment: Yes, it needs a little more logic for the other possible dates. Have a look at this thread for better ways of doing this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972712/generate-random-date-between-two-dates-using-php

Comment: @quentin: and the poor people born on Jan 31st... they just don't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`str_pad`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php).

```
echo $dob = str_pad($dob_month, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) . '/' . str_pad($dob_day, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) . '/'.$dob_year;
```

Comment: How the hell would this work? `number_format` formats decimal places.

Comment: @Kolink Updated. Check now. :)

Comment: Now you're saying to use `number_format`, and then not using it in your example :p

Comment: `sprintf` is still better XD

Comment: Sure, but then so does `($dob_month<10?'0':'').$dob_month`, and it doesn't involve a function call at all.

Answer (score 7):

How about:

```
$min = strtotime("47 years ago")
$max = strtotime("18 years ago");

$rand_time = mt_rand($min, $max);

$birth_date = date('%m/%d/%Y', $rand_time);
```

Basically: generate a couple of unix timestamps that represent your allowable date rage, then use those timestamps as the min/max ranges of the random number generator. You'll get back an int that just happens to be usable as a unix timestamp, which you can then feed into the `date()` and format however you'd like.

This has the added benefit/side-effect of allowing you to get a randomized birth TIME as well, not just a date.

Answer (score 4):

In this particular case, you can use `sprintf`:

```
echo sprintf("%02s/%02s/%04s",$dob_month,$dob_day,$dob_year);
```

However, I would suggest handling dates as dates:

```
$min = strtotime("jan 1st -47 years");
$max = strtotime("dec 31st -18 years");
$time = rand($min,$max);
echo $dob = date("d/M/Y",$time);
```

Comment: plus 1 for the concept of using dates as dates!

Comment: Simplest solution I've seen

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sprintf`, `str_pad`, or `date` with `strtotime` to get you what you want.

Another this to note is in your code you are making the statement

```
rand(01,12);
```

and with the leading 0 it is being interpreted as an octal number.  In this case it's not an issue becuase 01 == 1 but if you where trying to get a month in the last quarter, 09 is an invalid octal number and php will interpret it as 0. See the warning at http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php for details

Comment: +1 for the warning on octal numbers - I would've mentioned it if I hadn't removed the need for them XD

Answer (score 0):

Use `str_pad` --> [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php)

```
$dob = str_pad($dob_month, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT).'/'. str_pad($dob_day, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT).'/'.$dob_year;
echo $dob;
```

Comment: So allowing February 30th and disallowing January 31st isn't a problem?

Comment: The logic for generating the `date` needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same need, get a random date. So here is my solution. Generate absolutly valid date.

```
// Random birthdate between age
function get_random_birthdate_by_age($min_age, $max_age)
{
    $age = rand($min_age, $max_age);
    $birth_year = date("Y") - $age; // Current year - age
    return date("d.m.Y", strtotime("01.01.{$birth_year} +" . rand(0, 365) . " days"));
}

// Random birthdate between age 0 - 110
function get_random_birthdate()
{
    return get_random_birthdate_by_age(0, 110);
}
```