# PHP: Creating a random date from unix_timestamp

Tags: php, function, unix-timestamp

I'm wanting to create function that create's random time stamp between **Monday-Saturday** from another timestamp within 2-3 weeks.

```
function randomdate3weeks($timestamp){

     $add3weeks = strtotime('-21 day', $timestamp);

     $finaldate = mt_rand($add3weeks, $timestamp);

return $finaldate;
}
```

How would I add +1 or -1 day if it lands on a Sunday?

Comment: You're going to have to write your own function.

Comment: To explain all the downvotes, the site is not here to get others to do your homework for you. What have you tried and what results have you got? Where are you stuck?

Comment: considering that a timestamp is just a constantly incrementing number, what you are looking for is a way to pick a random number between two numbers. I would start with mt_rand.

Comment: I'm not trying to get people do to my homework for me. Sorry that it came off like that.  I came across this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972712/generate-random-date-between-two-dates-using-php) The issue I am having with it is how do I check for Monday-Saturday?

Comment: `function randomdate3weeks($timestamp){

     $add3weeks = strtotime('-21 day', $timestamp);

     $finaldate = mt_rand($add3weeks, $timestamp);

return $finaldate;
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
$from = 1405361280;
$from = DateTime::createFromFormat('U', $from);

$to = clone $from;
$to->modify('+3 weeks');

do {
  $random = rand($from->getTimestamp(), $to->getTimestamp());
  $random = DateTime::createFromFormat('U', $random);
} while (!$random->format('w'));

echo $random->getTimestamp();
```

In this code `$from` is the original timestamp, `$to` is 3 weeks from that timestamp. Then a `do..while` loop generates a random timestamp between these two and stops when the random timestamp is not Sunday.

It uses [`DateTime::format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) to check whether the generated time is Sunday or not. The `w` format character returns `0` for Sunday, `1-6` for the other days. So the loop stops when the result of `$random->format('w')` is greater than 0.

Comment: Thank you Gergo!  This has been very helpful.