# PHP to generate random date

Tags: php

I want a php script that generates random time:

For eg

`first time : 2014-02-14 10:21:02
next time  : 2014-02-14 08:21:02`

only time changes date doesnot change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it with mt_rand() like this:

```
echo date('Y-m-d')." ".mt_rand(0, 23).":".mt_rand(0, 59).":".mt_rand(0, 59);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$first_date = "2014-02-14 10:21:02";
$second_date = "2014-02-14 08:21:02";

$first_time = strtotime($first_date);
$second_time = strtotime($second_date);

$rand_time = rand($first_time, $second_time);
$rand_date = date('Y-m-d g:i:s', $rand_time);

echo $rand_date;
```

**[DEMO](https://eval.in/174787)**

**UPDATE:** today's random date

```
$first_time = strtotime(date('Y-m-d'));
$second_time = $first_time+86400;

$rand_time = rand($first_time, $second_time);
$rand_date = date('Y-m-d g:i:s A', $rand_time);

echo $rand_date;
```

**[DEMO](https://eval.in/174796)**

Comment: This is neat as it gives you the ability to easily set a lower and upper boundary for the possible random dates.

Comment: Well, the point is he only wants random times and not random dates.

Comment: @SKRocks: Can you tell me why you're always using strtotime()? strtotime() can be very inaccurate since it has to guess the dateformat. For example `2014-07-05`, it could be Y-m-d or Y-d-m and that's a huge difference. mktime() would be more appropriate.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois because its simple and easy to use

Comment: @SKRocks You may use whatever you want, but just because it's simple and easy to use, it doesn't mean it does everything right.

Comment: there is `DateTime` for further

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rand`  for this purpose

```
$int= rand(1262055681,1262055681);
```

You can use `mt_rand` too

```
$int= mt_rand(1262055681,1262055681); which provides better randomness in the results
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972712/generate-random-date-between-two-dates-using-php) for the reference