# Get random time using todays date

Tags: php

I need to get random time from today. I have tried using this

```
$today = date('YmdHi');
$startDate = date('YmdHi', strtotime('-0.5 days'));
$range = $today - $startDate;
$rand = rand(0, $range);
$smthing=$startDate + $rand;

return $smthing;
```

But it is not working correctly.

For example i want to generate todays date and whatever from it.

**Expected output**

> 2015:25:09 14:10:20
>
> 2015:25:09 08:12:26
>
> 2015:25:09 01:02:24

Comment: why can't you use just `time()`. After all it changes all the time! :D

Comment: @JitendraPurohit Nice one! chuckle chuckle

Comment: this might help [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972712/generate-random-date-between-two-dates-using-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use

```
$date=date('Y:m:d');
$sttime=strtotime($date.' '.'00:00:01');
$entime=strtotime($date.' '.'23:59:59');
$rand=rand($sttime,$entime);
echo $rand_time=date('Y:m:d H:i:s',$rand);
```

As per your question it will generate time intervals between the current day only

Comment: consider using mt_rand instead of rand(); http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php it's bascially a bit more random and faster.

Comment: Thank you! Also i put $date=date('Y:m:d'); instead 23:59:59. Now i am getting random time between 00:00:00 and current time :) 

Thank you one more time !