# Getting random date between two dates

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

Is there a way I can get a random date between two dates in Carbon? For example, I am trying to get a random date between now and 55 mins ago.

```
$dateNow = Carbon::now();
$date25MinsAgo = Carbon::now()->subMinutes(55);
```

However, I am stuck at this point. I found some info on php, but I want to use 'now' as it's a seeder. What should I do?

Comment: Already answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1972717/5139222)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate random date between two dates using php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972712/how-to-generate-random-date-between-two-dates-using-php)

Comment: @KuKeC that uses date() not carbon.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Use [`rand()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php):

```
 $random = Carbon::now()->subMinutes(rand(1, 55));
```

Answer (score 12):

To get a random date in the last year:

```
$random = Carbon::today()->subDays(rand(0, 365));
```

Comment: Nice, I'm using `$random = Carbon::today()->addDays(rand(1, 365));`

Answer (score 3):

Use [`random_int()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.random-int.php):

```
 use Carbon\Carbon;

 $upTo55MinsAgo = Carbon::now()->subMinutes(random_int(0, 55));
```

> (PHP 7, PHP 8) random_int — Generates cryptographically secure pseudo-random integers

You can also use `rand()`, but I think it's good practice to use the
cryptographically secure function.