# In Laravel, how do you create multiple factory models with different 'created_at' values?

Tags: php, laravel, testing

I have a User model and a Car model, and a User can have many Cars, and the `cars()` relationship should return the user's cars from the most recently created. Here's the test I've written for this relationship:

```
public function test_user_has_many_cars_relation_returns_cars_from_the_most_recent() {

   $user = User::factory()->create(); 
   $lessRecentCar = Car::factory()->for( $user )->create(); 
   sleep(1); 
   $mostRecentCar = Car::factory()->for( $user )->create(); 

   $hasManyRelation = $user->cars(); 

   $this->assertHasManyRelation( $hasManyRelation, Car::class, 2 );
   $this->assertIsSameModel( $mostRecentCar, $hasManyRelation->first() );

}
```

This works, however I had to use `sleep(1)` to create two cars with a different `created_at` value, because unfortunately using `Car::factory()->for( $user )->count(10)->create()` (which is a lot nicer) assigns the same value for `created_at` to all models.

Is there a better workaround than using `sleep(1)`? Hopefully something that doesn't imply manually assigning a different `created_at` value for each model one wants to create?

Comment: Do you _need_ the `created_at` values to be different? Does the test fail if they have the same timestamp there? You could always check `$mostRecentCar = $user->cars()->latest()->first()` after the Factory has created them, then `$hasManyRelation = $user->cars()->latest()`, and you _should_ get the correct result.

Comment: At a guess, I would think add created_at to your definition, use [Carbon to create a random timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41737423/getting-random-date-between-two-dates)

Comment: Try adding created_at field in factory too. It should look like this `'created_at' => $this->faker->dateTimeBetween('-1 year', 'now')`

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/factory-created-at Here it shows how to create different created_at

Comment: If I use random values for 'created_at', then how do I know which is the most recently created to pass to `assertIsSameModel`? I would have to run a check on the 'created_at' values, which would make the test messier than it already is.

Comment: @TimLewis yes the test fails if the created_at values are all the same, because then `$user->cars->first()` always returns the first model that was created (while I expect the last one). Will think about your proposed solution.

Comment: *"how do I know which is the most recently created to"* - What I said in my first comment: `$mostRecentCar = $user->cars()->latest()->first()`. Sidenote, you could use `id` too: `$mostRecentCar = $user->cars()->latest('id')->first()`; if the `created_at` timestamps are all the same, sort by `id`s instead, which should be sequential (auto-incrementing)

Comment: Yes but then I'm using the relationship under test in the 'arrange' part of the test...

Comment: Not 100% sure what you mean by that. But, it could also be said that you're testing vendor code when you don't need to. `->latest()`, `->first()`, etc., are Laravel functions, which have their own suite of tests on the Framework. `->first()` will always return `null` or an instance of a `Car` model, `latest()` will perform an `ORDER BY ...` based on the passed column, or `created_at`, by default, etc. etc. Why do you need to test these at all? Testing the Relationship is good to ensure DB columns/references are working, but the order feels irrelevant. But that's just my 2¢'s w/rt testing.

Comment: The issue is pretty clear, your test makes no sense, that is why you are strugling with it and there are a lot of comments trying to help in a different way... the only "custom" code you have in there, is the relationship itself, and you do not test relationships... you are literally testing the framework, not your code. If you want to test the relationship, use it in a real scenario, hence a Feature test, and if it fails due to the relationship, fix it and done, and more tests should fail if tha is the case, so delete this test and just create a feature test that is correct and done...

Comment: My `cars` relation in the User model looks like this: `public function cars() {
      return $this->hasMany( Car::class )->orderBy( 'created_at', 'desc' ); }` which is not the framework's default behavior (I believe by default Laravel orders relationship results in ascending order). This is why I'm testing it.

Comment: @grazdev it does not matter, you are still testing the framework, it will for sure order if you do so, and you never order relationships unless it is the default behaviour you want to change, it is a yes in your case, so don't test the framework, again, create a normal feature test where you need to test something using the relationship, if it is not in order in that feature test (the data created) then the test should fail, else it should not matter if your data is ordered or not. Again, this test should be deleted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- make sure to enable mass assignment for your Car model first
- use `faker` to override `created_at` in `create()` method:

```
$user = User::factory()->create(); 
$randomCarA = Car::factory()->for( $user )->create(['created_at'=>fake()->date()]);
$randomCarB = Car::factory()->for( $user )->create(['created_at'=>fake()->date()]);
```

Edit: to get most recent car:

```
$mostRecentCar=Car::latest()->first();
```

Comment: This works, however instead of doing `Car::factory()->for( $user )->create(['created_at'=>fake()->date()]);` I've used the suggestion in the comments to create a random `created_at` value in the Car factory definition, so in the test I'm using `Car::factory()->for( $user )->count(10)->create()`; doing so, combined with `Car::latest()->first();`, achieves what I'm trying to do. Thank you.

Comment: great even better!  , happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a better workaround than using `sleep(1)` or manually assigning different `created_at` values. You can override the `created_at` value in the factory's definition using the `afterMaking` and `afterCreating` callbacks. Here's an example:

```
use Carbon\Carbon;

$factory->define(Car::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'user_id' => User::factory(),
        'created_at' => Carbon::now(), // set a default value
        // other attributes
    ];
});

$factory->afterMaking(Car::class, function ($car, $faker) {
    $car->created_at = Carbon::now()->subSeconds(rand(0, 3600)); // override the created_at value
});

$factory->afterCreating(Car::class, function ($car, $faker) {
    // do something after creating the car
});
```

In this example, we're using the `afterMaking` callback to override the `created_at` value for each Car model that is made by the factory. The `Carbon::now()->subSeconds(rand(0, 3600))` expression sets the `created_at` value to a random time within the past hour.

Note that we're using the `rand` function to generate a random number of seconds between 0 and 3600, which is equivalent to 1 hour. This ensures that each Car model will have a different `created_at` value and avoids the need for the `sleep` function.

With this approach, you can create multiple Car models for a User using the `Car::factory()->for($user)->count(10)->create()` method and each Car model will have a unique `created_at` value.