# how to get Random date between 2 date values using php?

Tags: php, gdlib

how to get Random  date between 2 date values using php ?

I am coding an application where i need to assign random date between two fixed timestamps

how i can achieve this using php i've searched first but only found the answer for php
And how can add i values in gd library

Comment: Please show us what are you trying.

Comment: $datestart = strtotime('2009-12-10');//you can change it to your timestamp;
$dateend = strtotime('2009-12-31');//you can change it to your timestamp;

$daystep = 86400;

$datebetween = abs(($dateend - $datestart) / $daystep);

$randomday = rand(0, $datebetween);

echo "\$randomday: $randomday\n";

echo date("Y-m-d", $datestart + ($randomday * $daystep)) . "\n";

Comment: You are asking "how to get Random date between 2 date values using php" and then you write "how i can achieve this using php i've searched first but only found the answer for php". Please clarify.

Comment: GD library is for manipulating images with PHP. Are you trying to create an imaged with the random date you generate?

Comment: Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972712/how-to-generate-random-date-between-two-dates-using-php/1972717#1972717

Comment: I dont knw how to do it. Can u tel how to do it? Please