# Get random day, month, year, day of the week

Tags: php, random

I need to create a random generated day of the week, date, month, year. The problem is that I don't know how  to consider the 28 days in February, as well the 30-31 days in different months. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Generate a random timestamp and format it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets hold this short, and here's [a link with kinda same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972712/how-to-generate-random-date-between-two-dates-using-php)

with mt_rand you can generate random timestamps between those two
use [Unix Timestamps](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php) for that
then convert that timestamp with the date function for either Day, Month, Year etc.

here's an example:

`$int= mt_rand(1232055681,1262055681);
$string = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$int);
echo "<p>$string</p><br>";`

hope this helps and welcome! :)

Comment: Thank you very much fro your help