# Generate a certain number of random timestamps spread as evenly as possible between 2 dates in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, function, datetime, timestamp

I am struggling with writing some code to generate a list of random timestamps that are as evenly spread between 2 dates as possible.

Let me explain.

I am trying to write a function that generates instant win moments based on how many rewards i have and for how long i have the game running.

Lets say i have 1000 rewards and i want to give them over 55 days at certain times of the day.

I need a function that will return me an array with the timestamps spread as evenly as possible between 2 dates:

e.g.

```
function generateTimestampArray($numberOfRewards, $startDate, $endDate)
```

and this would return something like

```
array("2022-01-10 18:38", "2022-01-10 19:38", "2022-01-10 19:56"....."2022-02-10 12:38");
```

So for the example above we have **1000** rewards that need to be given evenly for 55 days, means we need **18 rewards / day** for **54 days** and **28 in the 55th days** (not sure how this can be spread out more evenly as **1000/55 = 18.18**). So we need 18 timestamps per day spread out as evenly as possible throughout the day. **The end result being an array of timestamps with all of the 1000 timestamps.**

I have found some code for getting a random timestamp between 2 dates:

```
function randomDate($start_date, $end_date)
{
    // Convert to timetamps
    $min = strtotime($start_date);
    $max = strtotime($end_date);

    // Generate random number using above bounds
    $val = rand($min, $max);

    // Convert back to desired date format
    return date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $val);
}
```

So lets say i go trough each day and generate a certain number of random timestamps But have no idea how i can generate them as evenly as possible for each day.

**Quick example:**

Imagine you have the interval 1 and 10 and you have to get 3 numbers in this interval that are somewhat evenly spread. One solution can be 2, 5, 7, another can be 3, 7, 10, but 1,2,3 cannot be as they are not very evenly spread, nor 4, 5, 6 nor 8, 9, 10. I hope that makes sense.

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/1972717/20004462

Comment: I don't understand, you either want them _evenly_ spread, _or_ you want them random. How is both at the same time supposed to make any sense?

Comment: @CBroe Random timestamps can be evenly spread as you don't define them beforehand. You generate them between 2 intervals of time, so they are random. Imagine you have the interval 1 and 10 and you have to get 3 numbers in this interval that are somewhat evenly spread. One solution can be 2, 5, 7, another can be 3, 7, 10, but 1,2,3 cannot be as they are not very evenly spread, nor 4,5,6, nor 8,9,10. Did not know how else to explain it. I will edit and say "as evenly spread as possible"

Comment: @NirajGautam Unfortunately no, as that generates just one date between 2 intervals. You can see in my questions that i have that function already, but thank you so much.

Comment: Still not sure why you'd call 2, 5, 7 evenly spread then. The "distance" between 2 and 5 is 3, the distance between 5 and 7, is 2 - so how is that "even"? If you said, it can either be 2, 5, 8, or 3, 6, 9, then I could see where the "even" is here, but with your example, it still seems arbitrary and not actually quantifiable to me.

Comment: How about if you divided your interval into equal sized sub-intervals first - and then picked a random value from each of those intervals? It does not make that much sense when you think of the 1 to 10 example - but say your interval was one day / 24hrs, and you wanted 24 random values - then divide that day into 24 intervals, and pick a random timestamp from each of those - would that be good enough for your requirements? (Then the "even" part would be in that we pick the random number _from_ evenly sized intervals to begin with.)